# Does Derby support table and column comments?

Tags: sql, derby

Does Derby support table and column comments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By 'table and column comments' you mean the ability to associate a comment (e.g. a description of the table / column) with the object?  No, it doesn't I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Following up with [Will A's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3429613/521799) This currently (version 10.14.2.0) still isn't supported. I have created a feature request for this, which tracks potential future support: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-7008

Comment: It's now 2023, five years after the request was opened, and the feature is still not implemented. Don't stop believin' :)

Comment: @fire_water: Rather than commenting here, why not comment directly on the issue I created, and upvote it?